# f measurable then f^{-1}(Borel) measurable

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Prove that if real function $f$ is measurable on $R$ then for every borel set $B$ preimage $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable.

Proof in my textbook goes like this:

We know from previous problem that if $f$ is measurable then for every open set $U$ $f^{-1}(U)$ is measurable. Set X of subsets of $R$ such that preimage is measurable is sigma algebra is itself sigma algebra (easy to check). So X contain all open sets. Because family of borel sets is the smallest sigma algebra which contain all open sets then family of borel sets is contained in X.

My doubt is what if family of borel sets contain some set that is not in X however is still smaller? Then family of borel sets is NOT contained in X.

Comment: It is hard to understand what your question is. A very simple proof has been given to you. Which of the two steps is not clear to you?

Comment: I said
My doubt is what if family of borel sets have some set that is not in X however is still smaller? Then family of borel sets is NOT contained in X.

Comment: $X$ contains the open sets and is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets (i.e. the collection of Borel-sets) will be a subcollection of $X$. This is a *proof* that $X$ contains the Borel-sets. If you agree on this then it is time to say goodbye to the doubt you mention. The family of Borel-set apparantly *does not* have some set that is not in $X$.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. If there exist set A such that A is in collection of Borel sets but not in X then A cant be open so collection of Borel sets minus A would be "the real collection of Borel sets".